# Rebase or merge for staying in sync with remote readonly repository

Tags: git

In my use-case I want to mirror a remote repository, apply some patches to it (for integration in our solution) and create release for these patched versions.

Intuitively I would have chosen to rebase everytime I want to synchronize with the 3rd-party repository again so that the history then contains thirt party commits + our patches. Releases would happen on dedicated release branches and would therefor ensure, that we have a history of how we got to a release ( no tags on main then )

The team that I am in is using a merge strategy for the same use case already, so I am wondering what the benefit of merging is. To me it is much more complicated, as our delta to the original is much more scattered through the git history (the patch commits + maybe in some of the merge commits).

Is there a best practice for the mentioned use case?

Comment: I guess there is no best practice, but you need to realize difference between merge and rebase. Rebase replays your commits on top of "original" branch history. So it is like you were making each of your commits on actual "original" branch. And merge will simply take all your changes and bring them to "original" branch, at once (or vice versa, based on merge "direction"). Personally for me it seems that if sync is done not regularly, then merge is better and easier process.

Comment: Thanks! But why is it better?  I can see that it may be easier in some cases, but like I described in the question - it hides information: you cannot easily answer which commits contain changes to the "original" branch. You are also reducing all the potentially meaningful commits of the original to a single merge commit. And beeing forced to review my own adjustments each after the other on conflict shouldn't be that bad (assuming there are not really many and the adjustments are quite disjoint)

Comment: With merges, your changes may be more scattered in the history, but they're clearer, because you keep the information about when they happened. I would definitely merge in remote updates, not rebase them. You might have to invest time in learning how to interpret the Git logs from this workflow, but I think it's still the better choice, imho.